# SAS sumifs - Finding number of pills of certain types used by patients

Tags: sql-server, excel, sas

Input Data:

```
user    DOB                 UseDate            numPills Type
1   2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 2013-04-11 00:00:00.000 4   A
1   2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 2013-07-20 00:00:00.000 5   A
1   2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 2014-01-02 00:00:00.000 1   A
2   2013-01-02 00:00:00.000 2013-04-12 00:00:00.000 1   A
3   2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 2013-04-11 00:00:00.000 5   A
3   2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 2013-07-20 00:00:00.000 5   A
4   2013-01-02 00:00:00.000 2013-04-12 00:00:00.000 1   A
5   2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 2013-04-11 00:00:00.000 9   A
5   2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 2013-07-20 00:00:00.000 1   B
6   2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 2013-04-11 00:00:00.000 1   A
```

Desired output:

```
user    DOB                  UseDate            numPills Type      sumifs
1   2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 2013-04-11 00:00:00.000 4   A   9
1   2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 2013-07-20 00:00:00.000 5   A   5
1   2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 2014-01-02 00:00:00.000 1   A   0
2   2013-01-02 00:00:00.000 2013-04-12 00:00:00.000 1   A   1
3   2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 2013-04-11 00:00:00.000 5   A   10
3   2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 2013-07-20 00:00:00.000 5   A   5
4   2013-01-02 00:00:00.000 2013-04-12 00:00:00.000 1   A   1
5   2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 2013-04-11 00:00:00.000 9   A   9
5   2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 2013-07-20 00:00:00.000 1   B   1
6   2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 2013-04-11 00:00:00.000 1   A   1
```

I'm trying to implement Excel's SUMIFS in SAS Enterprise Guide. I've already done a similar thing in MS SQL Server 2008 using cursors.

My ultimate goal is to be able to traverse tuple by tuple. I'm also considering somehow grouping relevant records into sets, and see if I can use any set operations.

Data:
My sample records are drug prescriptions of patients, with each record detailing how many pills were bought. Hence, I need to count the number of pills for each patient, ideally into different bins.
ie.

Patient #1, Pill A, 3 pills

Patient #1, Pill A, 2 pills

Patient #1, Pill B, 1 pill

I need to create a new column (that uses "SUMIFS") that would produce for the first row:
Patient #1, Pill A, 5 pills

Thank y'all!!!

As requested (sorry about the formatting, I'm new to this forum):

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
/* Cursor code begins here */
DECLARE @baseRWpointer CURSOR                       -- Base (read, write) cursor
DECLARE @offsetRpointer CURSOR                      -- Offset (read only) cursor

DECLARE @baseDate datetime
DECLARE @baseUser integer
DECLARE @baseType varchar(5)
DECLARE @baseDOB datetime

DECLARE @cumulative integer
DECLARE @offsetCount integer

DECLARE @offsetDate datetime
DECLARE @offsetUser integer
DECLARE @offsetType varchar(5)
DECLARE @offsetNumPills integer
DECLARE @offsetDOB datetime

SET @baseDate = '1900-01-01'
SET @baseUser = -1
SET @baseType = NULL

SET @cumulative = 0
SET @offsetCount = 0

SET @offsetRpointer = CURSOR SCROLL KEYSET
    FOR
        SELECT D.[user], D.[DOB], D.[UseDate], D.[numPills], D.[Type]   
        FROM [Charles_DB].[dbo].[Table1] D
        ORDER BY D.[ID], D.[Type], D.[UseDate]
    --FOR READ ONLY
OPEN @offsetRpointer

SET @baseRWpointer = CURSOR
    FOR
        SELECT D.[user], D.[DOB], D.[UseDate], D.[numPills], D.[Type]   
        FROM [Charles_DB].[dbo].[Table1] D
        ORDER BY D.[user], D.[Type], D.[UseDate]
    FOR update of D.[sumifs]

OPEN @baseRWpointer

FETCH NEXT from @baseRWpointer
INTO @offsetUser, @offsetDOB, @offsetDate, @offsetNumPills, @offsetType

FETCH NEXT from @offsetRpointer
INTO @offsetUser, @offsetDOB, @offsetDate, @offsetNumPills, @offsetType

WHILE   (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN

    SET @baseUser = @offsetUser
    SET @baseType = @offsetType
    SET @baseDOB = @offsetDOB
    SET @cumulative = 0
    SET @offsetCount = 0

    /*  Main "SUMIFS" loop  */
    while ( 
            @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 AND 
            (@baseUser = @offsetUser)
            AND (@baseType = @offsetType)
            AND ((DATEDIFF(day,@baseDOB,@offsetDate)) <= 365)  )
    BEGIN
        Set @cumulative = @cumulative + @offsetNumPills
        Set @offsetCount = @offsetCount + 1

        FETCH NEXT from @offsetRpointer
        INTO @offsetUser, @offsetDOB, @offsetDate, @offsetNumPills, @offsetType

    END

    /*  Update the column "sumifs" for base row  
        Recall that D is [Charles_DB].[dbo].[Table1] */
    UPDATE [Charles_DB].[dbo].[Table1] 
        Set [Charles_DB].[dbo].[Table1].[sumifs] = @cumulative
        WHERE CURRENT OF @baseRWpointer

    /*  Make offset pointer catch up to base pointer */
    Set @offsetCount = -(@offsetCount - 1)
    FETCH RELATIVE @offsetCount from @offsetRpointer
    INTO @offsetUser, @offsetDOB, @offsetDate, @offsetNumPills, @offsetType

    /* Place this at the end to get the correct @@FETCH_STATUS output to avoid infinite loop  */
    FETCH NEXT from @baseRWpointer
    INTO @offsetUser, @offsetDOB, @offsetDate, @offsetNumPills, @offsetType




END

CLOSE @baseRWpointer
CLOSE @offsetRpointer
DEALLOCATE @baseRWpointer
DEALLOCATE @offsetRpointer
```

Comment: Please show the code you have in SQL Server as well as sample data and expected results.  Your question is rather incomplete.

Comment: I'm made some edits; would that suffice? I know I can just use SQL statements in SAS; I'm wondering whether there are other ways to perform the same task without sql statements. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the input data you have?

Comment: @CharlesC.W.Tsai - You will have better luck of getting a speedy response if you just post what your input data is and what your output data should look like. Please provide more examples in  each case.

Comment: cool, how about now? (sry about the column formatting)

Comment: @DomPazz thanks for the suggestion/reminder, I also wish it were that easy; i cannot simply use group since i need to consider any prescriptions that are within a given period of time (ie. 1-year). There is already a "1-line" SQL way: use join on two identical tables, and group by tbl 1 and sum prescriptions of tbl 2. However, I believe the resulting runtime would not be optimal given the underlying operations of unions. Therefore, I'd like to optimize runtime given a sorted table of ID, drug type, and prescription date. Regardless, much appreciation for your help~!! :)

Answer (score 0):

SAS has procedures PROC SQL, PROC FREQ, PROC SUMMARY, and PROC TABULATE.  The query and filter node in SAS Enterprise Guide will run a PROC SQL step so you should be able to group the results by patent, pill and then sum the number of pills.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not fully understanding what you want.

I'm assuming your dataset looks like what you give above (Patient, PillType, Pills).  This sounds like a simple SQL summary.

```
PROC SQL noprint;
create table PillSummary as
select Patient,
       PillType,
       sum(Pills) as Pills
  from MyTable
  group by Patient, PillType;
quit;
```

This will create a table called PillSummary with pill sums by patient and type.  If you are looking for something else, let me know.